# How to change SVG text?

Tags: html, svg

I am new to svg concept. I have a requirement of changing the text written in SVG. Text is "Isadora". The code in my theme for writing is as below:

```
 <header class="ip-header">
            <div class="ip-logo"></div>
            <div class="ip-loader">
                <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
                <svg style="display:none;" class="ip-inner" viewBox="0 0 80 80">
                    <path class="ip-loader-circlebg" d="M40,10C57.351,10,71,23.649,71,40.5S57.351,71,40.5,71 S10,57.351,10,40.5S23.649,10,40.5,10z"/>
                    <path id="ip-loader-circle" class="ip-loader-circle" d="M40,10C57.351,10,71,23.649,71,40.5S57.351,71,40.5,71 S10,57.351,10,40.5S23.649,10,40.5,10z"/>

                </svg>


                <script>
                  var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
                      swiffyobject, {  });
                  stage.start();
                </script>
            </div>
        </header>
```

I want to change the text "isadora" to  "The School Management".

Comment: There is no isadora in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SVG does not contain any text (not even as paths), but is used to display content using [Google Swiffy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Swiffy), which converts SWF to JSON on the server side and then renders the output in the browser.

We can only guess because your question does not provide that information, but if you are displaying an SWF with the `isadora` text, you need to edit that SWF unless you want to change everything.